# Dynamic SOQL with multiple conditions and undefined amount of variables

Tags: soql, query, dynamic-soql, regular-expressions, where

I have SOQL like this:

```
[SELECT id FROM  CONTACT where lastName =:lastName AND firstName = :firstName]
```

But what to do if  there are only lastName  variable? What if there are 3 variables or more?

I thought about regex and use just like any symbol, but how?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. One of the keys to success on this site is to include plenty of details. Someone who answers a question must first understand what the issue is, and the only thing we have to go on is whatever information you provide. Right now, I don't understand what it is that you're asking. You should [edit] your question to include more details about the problem you're trying to solve (and try to focus on the overall problem, rather than saying "I want to use dynamic SOQL/regex to solve this problem"). Including more examples generally helps too.

Answer (score 4):

You use [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm).

```
String[] filters = new String[0];
if(firstName != null) {
  filters.add('FirstName = :firstName');
}
if(lastName != null) {
  filters.add('LastName = :lastName');
}
// ... etc ... //
String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Contact ';
if(filters.size() > 0) {
  query += ' WHERE ' + String.join(filters, ' AND ');
}
return Database.query(query);
```

Or you could use a QueryBuilder type class (e.g. from [fflib](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/blob/master/sfdx-source/apex-common/main/classes/fflib_SObjectSelector.cls)), or something else. It really just depends on how complicated you want it to be.